# Bundler::MarshalError TypeError: incompatible marshal file format + Ruby CAS Server

Tags: ruby-1.8.7, rubycas-server

I have clone the `rubycas-server` project and followed the steps as they mentioned in their documentation. When I am doing the `bundle install` I am getting the following error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/....Retrying dependency api due to error (2/4): Bundler::MarshalError TypeError: incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
format version 4.8 required; 60.72 given
Retrying dependency api due to error (3/4): Bundler::MarshalError TypeError: incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
format version 4.8 required; 60.72 given
Retrying dependency api due to error (4/4): Bundler::MarshalError TypeError: incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
format version 4.8 required; 60.72 given
```

I don't know why this message is coming and I am using Ruby 1.8.7.
Is any step missed or which ruby version is appropriate for running the Ruby CAS Server?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
bundle install --full-index
```

Which forces fresh download of index